# How do I redirect my WordPress site homepage to a landing page, while allowing the rest of the site to remain unaffected?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mobile

Here is the simple code I have placed before the  on the Wordpress site:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- if (screen.width <= 800) {
window.location = "http://m.domain.com"; } //--> </script>
```

This issue is, this redirects all pages of our site to to the landing page. I only want the home page to be redirected.  How would I write this?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in header.php of your theme.

```
    <?php
    if (is_front_page()) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "http://m.domain.com"; } //--> </script>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have another question about this.  I would now like to redirect all except two pages on the site to the mobile landing page.  In order to do this, I have placed the original code in the Wordpress site's header.php file. Is there way to exclude two specific pages on the site and redirect them somewhere else? For example, one of the pages is https://www.advancedcommission.com/apply-now/, and I would like to redirect it to http://www.advancedcommission.com/ac-apply-now-1/ instead.  Is this a simple fix?

Comment: Here is the code I've used     <?php
    if (is_page(‘221')) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "http://www.advancedcommission.com/ac-apply-now-1/"; } //--> </script>';
    }
    ?>     But it does not seem to be overriding the original code.

Comment: `<?php
    if (is_page(221)) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "http://domain-for-redirect-1"; } //--> </script>';
    } elseif (is_page(222)) { 
     echo '<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "http://domain-for-redirect-2"; } //--> </script>';
    }
    else { 
     echo '<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "http://m.domain.com"; } //--> </script>';
    }
    ?>`

Comment: Thank you.  I used this code, but for some reason, the site stopped redirecting altogether.  It redirects when I only use the one script, but as soon as I add in the other two, all mobile redirection stops. Any ideas?

Comment: <?php 
  if (is_page(221)) { 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
       <!-- if (screen.width <= 800) { window.location = "http://www.advancedcommission.com/ac-apply-now-1/"; } //--> </script>'; } 
  elseif (is_page(108)) { 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
       <!-- if (screen.width <= 800) { window.location = "https://www.advancedcommission.com/terms-and-conditions/"; } //--> </script>'; } else {echo '<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- if (screen.width <= 800) { window.location = "https://www.advancedcommission.com/mobile/"; } //--> </script>'; } 
?>

Comment: You are using ";;", try to use ";" (one simbol).

Comment: Sadly this still does not seem to be working.  I am putting it in the header.php file. Is this the correct place?  Or is there something else that I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Redirects with javascript can cause your website to be penalized by Google.

You are much better off using a Header redirect with PHP. You can detect mobile users based on their user agent rather that relying solely on the width of the browser window.

If you can't write all the code yourself, this plug-in could be helpful for that.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/equivalent-mobile-redirect/

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.  I will look into this plugin!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code right at the top of your themes header.php

```
<?php
    if(is_front_page())
        header('Location: http://example.com');

?>
```

This will only redirect on the front page. Just replace example.com with your desired url.

To setup a redirect for a different but specific page, you can use get_the_ID().

e.g.

```
<?php
    if(is_front_page())
        header('Location: http://example.com');
    elseif(get_the_ID() == PAGE ID HERE)
        header('Location: http://example2.com');
    elseif(get_the_ID() == PAGE ID HERE)
        header('Location: http://example3.com');
?>
```

if you want to redirect on all pages but still have homepage go somewhere else and leave some pages alone, use the below code.

```
<?php
    if(is_front_page())
        header('Location: http://example.com');
    elseif(get_the_ID() != PAGE ID HERE || get_the_ID() != 2ND PAGE ID HERE)
        header('Location: http://example2.com');
?>
```